# Changing the style of an item in an array when looping through isn't working

Tags: javascript, arrays, styles, element

I am trying to change the borderColor of a list using a for-loop, so I used this code:

```
var listedItems = document.getElementsByTagName("UL");
for (var i = 0; i < listedItems.length; i++){
    listedItems[i].style.borderColor = "red";
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

Comparing listedItems[i] to other things in an if-statement seems to work, but changing the element that the array currently points to isn't working. I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work.

Providing all border style are set. If you don't have already set the borderWidth and borderStyle you cannot see the color :)

```js
var listedItems = document.getElementsByTagName("UL");
    for (var i = 0; i < listedItems.length; i++){
        listedItems[i].style.borderStyle = "solid";
        listedItems[i].style.borderWidth = "1px";
        listedItems[i].style.borderColor = "red";
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  </ul>

<ul>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  </ul>
```

or

```
var listedItems = document.getElementsByTagName("UL");
for (var i = 0; i < listedItems.length; i++){
    listedItems[i].style.border = "1px solid red";
}
```

Comment: then the error is somewhere else. This snippet works

Comment: Any idea if there is like, a common mistake that people make with regards to this ? The rest of my code checks out logically, and only this particular statement is causing me trouble.

Comment: The code is executed after the document ready, or at end of the body? Are you sure that the code is executed (maybe some error before happens). Have you tried to do a `console.log(listedItems[i])` inside the for? What's the output?

Comment: The code is executed at the start of the body, it is executed because using `el.style.borderColor` happens to work, but listedItems[i] does not.

Comment: I didn't see what you meant, yes UL runs first, the javascript is in a separate file.

Comment: So. What's wrong here? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdjRMe (according with your code, the border style will be visible on theme picker click)

Comment: Nothing.. Looks like it just doesn't work with my computer for some reason?? I'm so confused..

Comment: I've used your code. I've simply replaced the borderColor with `listedItems[i].style.border="1px solid red"`

Comment: Sorry, but could you tell me why this doesn't work? I'm completely new and this is all so confusing for me. https://gyazo.com/250f82512c02e21880412503843bfec7